# Renomear arquivos com data em python

Tags: python, data

Gostaria de renomear arquivos de uma pasta e manda-los para outra, mas queria que ele contivesse a data ou que ele pelo menos colocasse um número após o nome caso já tivesse um igual.
O código é esse abaixo, mas como são varios arquivos que preciso mudar para mesma pasta, teria como alterar para colocar a data no final do nome ou um números crescentes?

```
os.rename('C:/scrapy/' + 'conta-completa.pdf','C:/scrapy/teste1/' + 'Teste.pdf')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O meu conselho é simplesmente renomear crescentemente, pois colocar a data como sufixo/prefixo (ex: dd-mm-yyy_hh:mm:ss) em um ciclo como este exemplo arriscarias muitos ficheiros com nomes iguais (iriam ser alterados no mesmo segundo ou até milisegundo):

Por comentário percebi que talvez tenhas de correr isto várias vezes, assim é preciso obter o último `n` do último ficheiro mudado para renomear o primeiro a seguir como `(n+1)_foo.pdf`:

```
import os

original_dir = 'caminho/para/pasta/original'
files = os.listdir(original_dir) # todos os ficheiros

last_num = max(int(i.split('_', 1)[0]) for i in files if '_' in i) # ultimo numero
no_changed_files = (i for i in files if '_' not in i) # ficheiros ainda nao mudados
for n, file_name in enumerate(no_changed_files, last_num + 1): # renomear os que ainda nao foram
    full_path = os.path.join(original_dir, file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(full_path)): # se for ficheiro
        os.rename(full_path, '{}/{}_{}'.format(original_dir, n, file_name))
```

Comment: substituiria esse file_name pelo nome do arquivo entre aspas?

Comment: O file_name já é o nome do arquivo @guilherme

Comment: Não deu certo, to procurando pelo o.rename um jeito mesmo,usando if ou for

Comment: Não deu certo? algum erro @guilherme? Seria só alterar neste exemplo as pastas original e destino

Comment: fala que src nao esta declarado

Comment: Erro meu @guilherme, desculpa, corrigido

Comment: Opa agora alterou o nome, muito obrigado, desculpa por abusar, mas se eu repito a ação ele altera os nomes novamente e coloca e fica 1_1_teste por exemplo, teria como nao acrescentar o 1_ se ja tiver?

Comment: Feito @guilherme

Comment: +1 pelo esforço rs, muito bom Miguel

Comment: @guilherme está feito para cobrir essa situação, estou a verificar se "_" existe já no `filename`

Comment: ficou muito bom, obrigado